# How to send an attachment from my internal phone memory using inbuilt email client?

Tags: android, email

I am developing an app in which i require to send files from my internal storage i.e. from path as shown by my phone.../sdcard/Android/data/com.proj.p/files
I think this is default path where package keeps its all files.
Now how to attach them to inbuilt email client suppose gmail..?

Comment: I believe the internal storage path is /data/data/<app package>/